# TFS : Can a shelveset be restored to another location?

Tags: unshelve, shelveset

I have the following scenario:

A user shelves some changes. Time goes by and a new branch of the product is created. Later, it is determined that the shelveset contains code, that we will need in the new branch.

By default; Visual Studio can only restore the shelveset changes to the location where they were shelved from. Is it possible to restore my shelveset in the new branch ? I do not want the code to be checked into the original branch, as it would break stuff.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117337/can-i-unshelve-to-a-different-branch-in-tfs-2008

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is possible with the TFS Power Tools.

See: 
[Can I unshelve to a different branch in tfs 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117337/can-i-unshelve-to-a-different-branch-in-tfs-2008)

Note the "migrate" option.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the overview about this command
[Unshelve command basics](http://codereferences.blogspot.com/2012/02/migrating-shelveset-from-one-branch-to.html)

From the article, an example:

```
tfpt unshelve "demo_shelveset";rkandhal /migrate /source:"$/Code-branch-1" /target:"$Code-branch-2/"
```