# TFVC equivalent (or similar) to Git's cherry-pick?

Tags: tfs, tfvc

Using TFVC, is there any way to do an operation similar to Git's cherry-pick command?

As an example, let's say I have 2 TFVC branches - `$/master` and `$/branch`.

`$/branch` has the following changesets that `$/master` does not:

```
1 - Add foo feature
2 - foo bugfix
3 - Add bar feature
4 - foo bugfix #2
```

Let's pretend that we want to merge this new `foo` feature into `$/master` and the related bugfixes, but we don't want the `bar` feature from the branch.

Is there any way to cherry-pick changesets 1, 2, and 4 (skipping 3), to bring their changes into `$/master`? I believe I would be able to merge those specific changesets *one at a time* into `$/master` if I wanted to keep each change isolated within its own changeset, but is there any shorter way?

Comment: already answered here too 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636925/what-is-the-equivalent-in-tfs-of-git-cherry-pick