# Create TFS 2010 branch from checked out items?

Tags: tfs, branch

I've edited some files in Branch1 and found out I would like to check the pending changes in to a new branch, Branch2. Is this possible?

I know I can create the branch as normally and then copy all the changed files to Branch2 by hand but that can be cumbersome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shelve your changes and the unshelve them into another branch: [Can I unshelve to a different branch in tfs 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117337/can-i-unshelve-to-a-different-branch-in-tfs-2008)

Comment: Nice. Too bad it's not part of the GUI (or part of the built in cmd line tools for that matter)