# TFS - TFPT - how to resolve conflicts when applying a shelveset from a branch to another?

Tags: tfs, merge-conflict-resolution, tfs-power-tools

I'm trying to apply a shelveset from a branch to another, following these steps:

> http://benjii.me/2014/04/move-shelveset-to-different-branch-in-tfs/

But when TFS opens a screen for me to resolve conflicts, it's impossible to work, because my shelveset has more than 700 files. I can't specify the desired merge option for each one.

What I need is to specify a default merge action for all the unresolved conflicted files at once.

Is it possible? If so, how can we do it?

Comment: Select all (control-A), then click the resolution strategy you want to apply.

Comment: @EdwardThomson, it doesn't work for TFS 2012. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no way to do so through power tools. When you are moving a shelveset of multiple files between branches, you must need to resolve the conflicts produced manually.

However there is another way to move a shelveset to another branch.
Please see the  answer from *Simon_Weaver*   [Can I unshelve to a different branch in tfs 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117337/can-i-unshelve-to-a-different-branch-in-tfs-2008)